# Mostrar perfil de usuario por sesiones PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un sistema donde el menú se muestra dependiendo el tipo de usuario (administrador, organizador y usuario común) quiero crear una página donde muestro la información del usuario loggeado sea cual sea, pero al crear la página de perfil.php no muestra nada.

El código que he tratado de implementar para mostrar el perfil del usuario loggeado es el siguiente, la sesion ya esta iniciada en menu2.php:

Documento: PERFIL.PHP

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
require 'DBusuarios.php';
?>
```

---

```
<body>
<?php include 'menu2.php';?>

            <?php
            $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
            $sql = "SELECT usuario, nombre, ap, correo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario ='$usuario'";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            ?>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                             <br /><thead bgcolor= "#9370D8">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Correo</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td name="usuario" value="<?php echo $row['usuario']?>"></td>
                                    <td name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']?>" ></td>
                                    <td name="ap" value="<?php echo $row['ap']?>" ></td>
                                    <td name="email" value="<?php echo $row['correo']?>" ></td>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Esta es la funcion que permite el login, se encuentra en DBusuarios.php, aqui tiene la sesion de usuario, ya que la incluí en PERFIL.PHP, no muestra errores pero tampoco los datos

```
function login($usuario, $password) {
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, usuario, id_tipo, password FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? || correo = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $usuario);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result( $id, $usuario, $id_tipo, $passwd);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $validaPassw = password_verify($password, $passwd);
            if($validaPassw){
                lastSession($id);
                $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $id_tipo;
                        header("location:perfil.php");
                } else {
                $errors = "La contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecta";
            }
        } else {
        $errors = "El nombre de usuario o correo electr&oacute;nico no existe";
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Tienes `session_start()` dos veces

Comment: Sí, pero si la quito del menú ya no funciona y quiero incluirlo en todas las pantallas para no estar reescribiendo el menu en todaas las paginas

Comment: No necesitas reescribirlo, solo incluirlo

Comment: Hola @LissetK.Santes, El session_start(); debe estar antes de tu database conection. En caso de declararlo 2 veces lo que haces es sobre escribir la sesion del usuario (el primer error) revisa la documentacion [$_session](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php). En otro lado el error dice que el valor 'usuario' no esta definido, puedes agregar el query de tu base de datos? para revisar tu segundo error

Comment: Lo que hay aquí es un problema de organización de tu código. `session_start()` debe ponerse **una sola vez**, en el primer archivo que se carga. Luego, en ninguna parte se ve dónde asignas un valor para `usuario` en la variable de sesión.

Comment: Mhh, no entiendo bien como darle el valor, no había usado sesiones antes por lo que comprendo, según lo que leí en la documentacion ya tenía el valor

Comment: Por eso digo que el problema principal es de **organización de código**. La variable de sesión es una variable, como cualquier otra variable, sólo que persiste. Pero para que tenga determinados valores los mismos deben ser asignados en alguna parte. Por tanto, analiza tu código para determinar en qué parte de él la variable de sesión debería tomar un valor asociado a una clave llamada `usuario`.

Comment: Si observas [los ejemplos del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php), verás cómo a la variable de sesión se le asignan valores asociados a claves (`color, animal, instante`) ... Los valores se asignan del mismo modo que se asigna un valor a una clave de un array. Significa que para poder hacer esto: `$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];` primero, en alguna parte del flujo de tu código, tuvo que haber ocurrido algo como esto: `$_SESSION['usuario']="Valor o Variable para usuario";`

Comment: He editado la pregunta, esto que mencionas de la $_SESSION lo tengo en mi funcion para el login, ya que lo incluí en Perfil.php ahora no muestra error pero tampoco los datos

Comment: Repito, otra vez, se trata de un problema de **organización del código**. ¿Podrías explicar cómo tienes organizado el código? Esto no queda claro en la pregunta. ¿En qué archivo tienes el problema? ¿Qué flujo estás siguiendo (cargo primero esto, y luego esto y luego esto otro)? ¿Dónde inicias la sesión? ¿Dónde la asignas valores a la sesión? ¿Dónde intentas leer datos de la sesión? Si llegas a explicar la organización de tu código encontrarás la solución al problema y entenderás tu código y el contexto en el que estás programando y cualquier problema futuro será más fácil de resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentas que ya tienes identificados los valores de las variables de sesión, entonces el problema podría ser el como estas mostrando esos datos.

Como las variables ya están cargadas en la memoria al momento que realiza el login, lo único que se hace es "llamarlas" , "invocarlas" o el termino que gustes y colocarlas en donde las necesites.

De esta manera yo coloco los datos obtenidos de las variables de sesión debajo de un banner o una barra que contiene un logo y un color de fondo, se muestra el nombre del usuario, el puesto que tiene, y su rol, en una pequeña lista y orientada hacia la derecha de la pantalla, alineados de la mejor manera posible.

Y de esta forma es como muestro los datos de las variables de sesión debajo del banner(barra)

```html
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <span class="name pull-left" style="color: #FF8200" >
                    
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-left">
                        <strong>USUARIO:</strong>
                        <span class="name pull-rigt" style="color: #21BA45"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['USUARIO'];?></strong></span>
                    </div><BR>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-left">
                        <strong>PUESTO: </strong>
                        <span class="name pull-rigt" style="color: #d58512"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['PUESTO'];?></strong></span>  
                    </div><BR>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-left">
                        <strong>ROL: </strong>
                        <span class="name pull-rigt" style="color: #007DBB"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['ROL'];?></strong></span>
                    </div>
               </span>     
        </div>
```

Adicionalmente algunos datos que se obtienen al realizar el login, con las variables de sesión me permite realizar consultas en mysql especificas para el usuario.

Espero te sirva para que resuelvas el inconveniente que tienes.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué 2 respuestas?, ¿no quedan ambas en la misma aportación?

Comment: Excelente, me ha ayudado y he podido solucionarlo, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como menciona A. Cedano para crear tus variables de sesión puedes hacer algo parecido a esto, tendrás que modificar según sea tu estructura de desarrollo :

Yo utilizo un archivo al cual le denomino crear_variables_inc.php
lo básico que ya te han mencionado colocar el session_start();  y declarar tus variables de sesión de la siguiente manera, no es la única manera pero eso ya es cuestión de investigar como se adapten a tu codigo.

```html
     $_SESSION['USUARIO']=$resultado[$i]->getApellido1()." ".$resultado[$i]->getApellido2()." ".$resultado[$i]->getNombre();
   $_SESSION['ID_ROL']=$resultado[$i]->getId_Roles();
```

Esto es utilizando clases, de esta manera obtengo el nombre del usuario, su RFC, el ROL de usuario, Puesto, y claves de usuario. (Y lo que se pueda ocurrir o necesites)

Para que después pueda utilizarlos en los menús que se despliegan según el Rol que tiene cada persona.

```html
<body>
        
        <div class container>
            <div class="menu_padre"> <-- CSS
                <div class="tab-pane active" style="text-align: center">
                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                        
                        <?php if ($_SESSION['ID_ROL'] == 1 ){?>
                        // Aqui incorporo los elementos que podrá visualizar por cada rol                   
                        <li> icono +  enlace</li>
                        <li> icono +  enlace</li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ($_SESSION['ID_ROL'] == 2 ) { ?>
                        <li> icono +  enlace</li>
                        <li> icono +  enlace</li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ($_SESSION['ID_ROL'] ==  3 ) { ?>    
                        <li> icono +  enlace</li>
                        <li> icono +  enlace</li>
                       
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>       
   </div>
```

De esta manera garantizas que el usuario solo pueda ver determinado contenido lo que vendría siendo como decir los privilegios del usuario basado en roles.

Espero que te sea algo útil

Saludos

Comment: No tengo ningún problema con el menú, el problema es que no logro obtener y mostrar el perfil del usuario loggeado
Ya tengo ubicada la sesion, pero ahora no hay ningun error ni tampoco muestra los datos